# text input change class on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return buyukHarf(event);" class="green" name="f1"/>
```

is it possible to change the class `green` to something else when the area is clicked? Or any other way to change the border color when clicked?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("green").addClass("yellow");    
});
```

In the case of form elements, I'd use `focus()` and `blur()` over a `click()` handler.

Also, try to avoid using inline javascript as you have done in your example.

Focus/Blur example:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("green").addClass("yellow");
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("yellow").addClass("green");
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. one more question; how do i call the script on my form? sorry for my ignorance...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You'll have to explain further.

Comment: I add the codes you provided to the page but i think i need to add something like onBlur="what to write here" to my form?? Thanks again...

Comment: That's inline javascript. Try to avoid it. You don't need to use it in this case.

Comment: Have you included `jQuery` on your page? got the script inside a `document.ready()` function, or at the bottom of the page?

Comment: yes it is included. and i tried both... $(document).ready(function() {... }); used this :(

Comment: so sorry about that.. i think it was because the codes were over my jquery include. its working now. thanks  lot...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$( "input" ).click( function() {
    $( this ).attr( { 'class' : 'anotherClass' } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("input[name='f1']").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("green").addClass("red");    
});
```

OR // for border

```
$("input[name='f1']").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("green").css("border", "1px solid red");    
});
```